# what is the regex to use for Version numbers like 1.0.10.13 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a required to validate the version numbers using regex. I tried few but not working as expected.
Any idea what regex to use to validate versions like 1.0.10.135 in C#. Every number should grow upto 3 digits in each section.

Update I tried this "[\d]{1,3}.[\d]{1,3}.[\d]{1,3}.[\d]{1,3}" and it accepted "1.0.0.3@@", which is not correct.

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? also: does it _have_ to be a regex? i could very well see a numeric version. meaning: besides the built-in tools.

Comment: Why do you need a regex? The [`Version` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-5.0#methods) has `(Try)Parse`.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann: I tried this "[\d]{1,3}.[\d]{1,3}.[\d]{1,3}.[\d]{1,3}" and it accepted "1.0.0.3@@". Which I couldn't fix.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann: I am trying to use in some other scenario where I cannot put it directly. Have only limited options including regex.

Comment: Your `1.0.0.3@@` doesn't work with the just `\d{1,3}` pattern I show in my answer.  You could swap out `\d` with `[0-9]` if you want to be sure

Comment: What are these mystery “other scenario”s you aren't telling us?

Comment: @DourHighArch: Nothing mystery. I am using fluent validations and passing it as Func.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with a regex, I'm surprised you haven't found one that worked.  Here's a quick one (it worked the first time I tried it):

```
(?<major>\d{1,3})\.(?<minor>\d{1,3})\.(?<patch>\d{1,3})(\.(?<build>\d{1,3}))?
```

It names the parts, and makes the last part optional